# Truncation error when importing excel file to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to import a large file from excel into an sql table using the Import tool but I keep encountering the error below

[image]

I've already set all the columns to NVARCHAR(MAX) to accommodate the data but I still get the error.

Comment: That would make sense if the OP was using text file, @GordonLinoff , but for an xls(x) file commas in cells don't matter when you're importing those. To me, it's likely that the awful ACE drivers have been "kind" enough to decide what the length of the data is in your column (probably based on the first 10 rows). When you then get to a row which is longer than the definition for that column, the error occurs. This is just 1 of many reasons why the ACE drivers are really not great.

Comment: "_I've already set all the columns to NVARCHAR(MAX) to accommodate the data but I still get the error._" Did you recreate the import package after doing that? Because the original package will still have the data lengths from the original column definitions in it.

Comment: I created the table before creating the package so I have this problem from the beginning